# Recursive binary search (integer)

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, search, binary-search

I've written this binary search algorithm based on recursion but I'm unable to understand the reason for the error.

```
    // Only a sorted array must be entered for binary search to work
    public int binarySearch(int searchFor, int[] inArray, int from, int to){
        if (to >= from){
            int mid = (to-from)/2 + from;
            
            if (inArray[mid] == searchFor){
                return inArray[mid];
            } else if (inArray[mid] < searchFor){
                binarySearch(searchFor, inArray, ++mid, to);
            } else if (inArray[mid] > searchFor){
                binarySearch(searchFor, inArray, from, ++mid);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

```
at search.binarySearch(search.java:24)
at search.binarySearch(search.java:24)
at search.binarySearch(search.java:24)
at search.binarySearch(search.java:24)
```

Comment: I think you need add return inside `else if` calls

Comment: Check this example is very similar to your code. [Example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/). As mentioned @VedantTerkar you miss the word return in both "else if" instructions.

Comment: Add the input values to understand the problem

Comment: Besides the missing `return`s, you also miscalculate the upper bound when you go left: You want `mid - 1` here. (And I think you should return the index, `mid`, instead of the value `inArray[mid]`, which you already know.)

Comment: And you should have a way to deal with the fact that the element was not found.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues and remarks:

- In the last case, the value `++mid` is wrong as argument for `binarySearch`. That value should be one *less* than `mid` in that case.
- I would also vote against the use of `++mid` or `--mid` here, as that suggests that it is important that `mid` changes value, which is not needed. You should just pass `mid+1` in the first case, and `mid-1` in the second.
- `binarySearch` returns an `int`, but when your code calls it recursively it doesn't do anything with that return value.

  You should *return* that value. So:

  ```
              } else if (inArray[mid] < searchFor){
                  return binarySearch(searchFor, inArray, mid+1, to);
  //              ^^^^^^                                  ^^^^^
              } else if (inArray[mid] > searchFor){
                  return binarySearch(searchFor, inArray, from, mid-1);
  //              ^^^^^^                                        ^^^^^
              }
  ```
- The expression `(to-from)/2 + from` is a verbose way of doing `(from+to)/2`...

Comment: (The expression `(from + to) / 2` could overflow for large numbers. Using `(to - from) / 2 + from` prevents overflow. Probably not a concern here.)

Comment: Expression `(to-from)/2 + from` is a defensive measure against integer overflow :)

Comment: Yes, that would be a necessary precaution when dealing with arrays of at least 2³⁰ ints, i.e. 4GB.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from adding `return` to the recursive calls of `binarySearch`, there are a couple of flaws in the logic:

- `mid` should be *decremented* to catch values in the left part:

```java
    return binarySearch(searchFor, inArray, from, --mid);
```

- there should be a check for valid `mid`, `from`, `to` values to fit inside the input array

Thus, the method should look as:

```java
public static int binarySearch(int searchFor, int[] inArray, int from, int to) {
        if (to >= from && from > -1 && to <= inArray.length) {
            int mid = (to-from)/2 + from;
            
            if (mid >= inArray.length) {
                return -1;
            }
            
            // System.out.printf("from=%d to=%d mid=%d val=%d%n", from, to, mid, inArray[mid]); // debug print
            if (inArray[mid] == searchFor) {
                return inArray[mid];
            } else if (inArray[mid] < searchFor){
                return binarySearch(searchFor, inArray, ++mid, to);
            } else {
                return binarySearch(searchFor, inArray, from, --mid);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Tests:

```java
public static int binarySearch(int searchFor, int... inArray) {
    System.out.printf("Searching for %d in %s%n", searchFor, Arrays.toString(inArray));
    return binarySearch(searchFor, inArray, 0, inArray.length);
}

System.out.println(binarySearch(10));
    System.out.println(binarySearch(10, 10));
    System.out.println(binarySearch(10, 1));
    System.out.println(binarySearch(10, 0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 21));
    System.out.println(binarySearch( 0, 0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 21));
    System.out.println(binarySearch(21, 0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 21));
    
    System.out.println(binarySearch(10, 0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 21));
    System.out.println(binarySearch( 0, 0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 15, 21));
    System.out.println(binarySearch(21, 0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 16, 21));
    
    System.out.println(binarySearch(30, 0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 21));
    System.out.println(binarySearch(-1, 0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 21));
    System.out.println(binarySearch(7, 0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 21));
```

Output:

```
Searching for 10 in []
-1
Searching for 10 in [10]
10
Searching for 10 in [1]
-1
Searching for 10 in [0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 21]
10
Searching for 0 in [0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 21]
0
Searching for 21 in [0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 21]
21
Searching for 10 in [0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 21]
10
Searching for 0 in [0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 15, 21]
0
Searching for 21 in [0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 16, 21]
21
Searching for 30 in [0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 21]
-1
Searching for -1 in [0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 21]
-1
Searching for 7 in [0, 1, 5, 8, 10, 21]
-1
```